# Can a machine be found without its subnet mask?

Tags: networking, ip

If it is the subnet mask that identifies a network and therefore by exclusion, the machine in this network, then only one address can correspond to several machines. For example 164.24.86.86.18/16 does not correspond to the same address as 164.24.86.18/24. So for example when I enter an IP address without its mask in my browser, how can it find the machine without its mask?

Comment: The address of the host is just an address, not an address+mask, and compares for equality without regard to a mask. The network description with a mask is a way of designating a set of hosts, for example directly connected to each other. It is not necessary for the set in a routing table on one host to have the same elements as the set on the remote host itself.

Comment: Those 2 addresses *could* be the same. The mask simply denotes the local range of IPs, which is used in determining if another host is directly eachable or not. But the address is the unique part.

Comment: Those two addresses *are* the same. @Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP address and netmask serve different purposes.

- The IP address uniquely identifies a networking endpoint.
- The netmask is used by software and hardware between the originating endpoint and the destination endpoint to filter or categorize packets with a given IP.

For example, you may wish to block all traffic originating from Amazon Web Services. You can [download the file containing all AWS network ranges](https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json), which specify those ranges as netmasks. For example, `18.208.0.0/13`. Then you can run [iptables](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) to block traffic with IP addresses covered by that mask (for example, `18.208.12.34`).

Similar filtering happens inside routers. For example, in a network with multiple physical subnets, you can use netmasks to direct traffic to the appropriate subnet.

Your example `164.24.86.18/24` is, by the way, invalid. It should either be `164.24.86.18/32` (which masks all but a specific IP address) or `164.24.86.0/24` (which masks the /24 network range starting with `164.24.86`).